# Avoid overlapping circles in a geographic projection (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to crete data visualizations using Maps with geographic projection in d3.js

```
var projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
```

The idea is to use circles to represent some information about the countries. Can be area, population, religion, etc.

But the problem is that I don't know how to **avoid overlapping these circles**.

Here is the code that I'm working https://jsfiddle.net/Lxf9b6j9/

The circle radius is the area of the country. To convert km² to radius I use Math.sqrt(r.area/Math.PI)/50

I tried to use Collision detection and Clustered Force Layout from d3.js examples, but I did not succeed. The collision function they used did not work with my code.

Please, help me!

Comment: In what way are you hoping to avoid collision? Do you want the circles to move, or change size, or change shape...?

Comment: @RandyHall I want the circles to move. Size and shape must remain the same

Comment: The best approach here is using a force simulation with forceCollide and setting the forceX and forceY positions according to the centroids.